# Cannot retrieve the checkbox status

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have a table with some checkboxes in every row. There is a select element in the table footer with several options. When the user chooses an option, i want to pass the value of any checked checkboxes and the selected option to a php script.

This is the form:

```
<form name="doall" method="POST" action="action.php">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <?php for($j=0;$j<count($userToRead);$j++){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="selection_<?php echo $j ?>" name="objectSelected[<?php echo $userToRead[$j]['id'] ?>]" value="1"/>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo $userToRead[$j]['id'] ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" style="text-align:center;padding-left:15px;background-color:<?php echo $SListsStatus[intval($userToRead[$j]['userstatus'])][1]; ?>;" >
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo stripaccenti($userToRead[$j]['user']) ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo stripaccenti($SUserType[$userToRead[$j]['type']]['name']) ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo stripaccenti($userToRead[$j]['first_name']) ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo stripaccenti($userToRead[$j]['last_name']) ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo stripaccenti($userToRead[$j]['title']) ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="actBtns">
                        <a href="#" title="Update" class="tipS">
                            <img src="images/icons/edit.png" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" title="Remove" class="tipS">
                            <img src="images/icons/remove.png" alt="" />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } // end for ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="9">
                    <div class="itemActions">
                        <label>Con tutte le selezionate:</label>
                        <select name="whatDoAll">
                            <option value="1">Attiva</option>
                            <option value="2">Disattiva</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" value="Esegui" class="button redB" style="margin: 5px;"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>                
</form>
```

So in every line of my table I have a checkbox where the value is the ID of the db object that I need to modify with my php script.

This is my script:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    var output = '';
    $('input[type="objectSelected"]:checked').each(function(index) {
        output += $(this).val() + ", ";
    });
    alert(output + "is checked!");
});
```

In the php file i try to retrieve the variable with `$_POST['objectSelected']` but the variable is always empty. Also, the script alert is empty.

The tables are create with jquery: **if I use a pure html table with pure html checkboxes everything works!**

Comment: You are using somewhat overcomplicated selectors and I think the second one might be the problem.

Comment: `$('input[type="objectSelected"]:checked')` ... makes no sense to me ... shouldn't type be "checkbox"? so ... `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')` ... in your case you could even simplify it to `$("input:checked")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong. You are specifying input type then the code should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
                      var output = '';

                      $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index) {
                         output += $(this).val() + ", ";
                      });

                      alert(output + "is checked!");
                    });
  </script>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thankyou Sabari, now the alert is working and return to me the right values.

But the php is not working:

echo implode(', ', $_POST['objectSelected']) . ' are checked!';

output is "are checked!"

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="selection_<?php echo $j ?>" name="objectSelected[]" value="<?php echo $userToRead[$j]['id'] ?>

echo implode(', ', $_POST['objectSelected']) . ' are checked!';

result= none

Comment: @RobertoPezzali If the answer did NOT completely solve your problem, you do not have to accept it yet (and you can un-accept it). Do continue to work for a solution, but if you mark it as solved when it is not, you won't get any further answers and your problem won't get fixed.