# Checkbox status in php before submit form

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I was looking on here an Google to see if there was a way to test the status of a checkbox before the form was submitted. Everything I come up with is similar to this, but it is for after the form has been submitted.

```
    !isset($_POST['testBox']) 
    !isset($_GET['testBox'])
```

I know you can open a pop up box on the check event in VB.net but is there something like this in php/html. Or does it have to be done with javascript?

so you know I am pulling data from a database to check the checkbox, which works fine. I just want the user to see a message if they uncheck that box.

I found this page [Cannot retrieve the checkbox status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231357/cannot-retrieve-the-checkbox-status), but I'm not sure how to edit the javascript to comply with my code. I'm still learning javascript.

So basically what I need is either to check the status of the box before the form has been submitted or when it is submitted to throw up a message box stating my message and to tell the user if they wish to continue to click yes, if they click no to stop the process and go back to the form.

Comment: PHP is server side script only, you won't find your answer there.

Comment: I put in php because that is what the file was saved as it is not a .html it is a .php. I understand that it is a server side script, I am using it to populate a form from a database query, so it is relevant. Once I get the popup to work I am going to be using the code I posted above to save to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to show the alert when the checkbox gets unchecked, combine Newbie and Blaine answers into this:

```
$('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('unchecked');
    }
});
```

Comment: will this only throw up the message box if the checkbox has not been checked? That is what I need. Also I was looking you can't change the background color of an alert correct?

Comment: never mind I got it to work. I now just need to change the color. So inserting a new div I think is how it is done. If you have any further ideas on this that would be great.

Comment: Actually after a bit of messing around with it I got it to do what I want. I am having it show a div (that I can change the colors of) instead of showing the alert box. I just needed what you provided to catch if the checkbox was checked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side script, you have to hit the script for PHP to do anything. So to do what you are talking about, you would have to incorporate Javascript.

It might look like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" checked>
```

Javascript (using JQuery):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#mycheckbox").change(function() {
       alert("my alert"); 
    //execute code
   });
});
```

Here is a link:

http://jsfiddle.net/F3D2A/

Comment: do you have any tutorials or sites that I may be able to look at?

Comment: ok that works for the popup but can I tell it not to display when I check the box ?

Comment: Tell what not to display?

Answer (score 0):

As @Blaine said, PHP is a server-side script, you can check it via jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mycheckbox").change(function() {
      alert($("#mycheckbox").is(':checked')); 
      // It will return true or false: true = checked & false = not checked
   });
});
```